# Magento 2 - Display custom modules' Block before Add to Cart and after Short Description on Product Detail Page

Tags: magento2, product, layout, blocks

Custom Module - **layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
                <block class="Einfochips\ConcreteMix\Block\Index" name="concretemix_index" template="Einfochips_ConcreteMix::concretemix_prod_detail.phtml" 
                       after="product.info.price" before="product.info.addtocart" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Tried with above code but it is not working. Here I need to display my custom container before `Add to Cart` button and after product's `short description`

Comment: Can't add block before button addto cart untill you modifine block template.    Can only add some block after short description.

Answer (score 3):

You can add your custom block by layout via some default block such as `product.info.addtocart` `product.info.addtocart.additional` `product.info.options.wrapper` `product.info.options.wrapper.bottom`. All of them have

```
<?= echo $block->getChildHtml('', true); ?>
```

Allow you add your custom block as child block

Approach

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" 
           name="your-block-name" 
           template="your-block-template.phtml" />
</referenceBlock>
```

Another approach by add custom container

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
     <container name="product.info.afterprice" after="product.info.price" label="Product info afterprice" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-after-price">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" 
                   name="your-block-name" 
                   template="your-block-template.phtml" />
     </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

So the way depends on where you want do place block, you can change block reference for your requirement

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need your own container? Containers will not render by itself unlike blocks in containers. You have to call $block->getChildHtml(NAME); from parent block's template. I would rather simply add block inside of product.info.main. I do not see any profit for doing this at least not from the code you show us.

Comment: Rephrased my question. Not custom container, how do I call my custom module's block (html) before add to cart button and after short description ?